# EditText inside of an AlertDialog

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

What I want to do is: When someone click at a TextView it opens an AlertDialog with a EditText, the person writes something in the EditText, clicks at "Ok" and then the TextView is set to what the person wrote on the EditText.

But I got two problemas.

First: It's not working. When I click in "Ok" my app crashes and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Second: I also have more than one TextView and I have no idea how to set the text of an especific textview without having to create a new alertdialog for each textview. How can I identify in the Dialog if the person has clicked on TextView A or B? Or should I just create another AlertDialog?

My code:

```
public class Mec extends Activity implements OnClickListener {  
ImageView iv;

Button save;

TextView tSup, tInf;

EditText txt = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loud);
    bts();
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String vds = extras.getString("omec");
    if (vds.equals("Hello")) {
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.world);
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
}   
private void bts() {
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivID);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSave);
    tSup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSuperior);
    tInf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtInferior);
    txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
}
private void poptxt() {
    AlertDialog InserirTXT = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mec.this).create();
    LayoutInflater infle = getLayoutInflater();
    View txtlayout = infle.inflate(R.layout.poptxt, null);
    InserirTXT.setView(txtlayout);
    InserirTXT.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String texto = (String) txt.getText().toString();
            tSup.setText(texto);
        }
    });
    InserirTXT.setCancelable(true);
    InserirTXT.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    InserirTXT.show();
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btSave:
        //After
        break;

    case R.id.txtSuperior:
        poptxt();
        break;

    case R.id.txtInferior:
        poptxt();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Thank's for any help at all!

EDIT: 
Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="73.68"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/badluck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInferior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivID"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Bottom text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="35dp"
        style="@style/estilotxt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSuperior"
        style="@style/estilotxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivID"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:editable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Top text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btSave"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:text="Save" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
08-08 22:23:55.101: W/dalvikvm(322): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at vds.cmc.Mec$1.onClick(Mec.java:89)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:158)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-08 22:23:55.121: E/AndroidRuntime(322):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-08 22:23:56.950: I/Process(322): Sending signal. PID: 322 SIG: 9
```

EDIT: Thank you guys.

I tried iniciating the txt inside the AlertDialog but nothing worked so I decided to delete this part and rewrite it from scratch with a tutorial that I found. Now it's working, but I still have no idea what I did wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: For the crash, please post the LogCat output.

Comment: For problem 2, you can have something like tInf.setTag("textview1"); and you can identify it textView.findViewWithTag("textview1"); Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I've edited the post with logcat and layout.

Comment: And I think got it about the second question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do the following

create an xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:padding="10dp"
          >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
           />
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:textColor="#FFF"
          />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then create a dialog and set the layout as its contentview

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("Hello, this is a custom dialog!");
ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file and your LogCat output would be a help here, but even without it I can see a potential issue:

```
String texto = (String) txt.getText().toString();
tSup.setText(texto);
```

Given your description, I believe that `txt` is the edit field in your `AlertDialog`, so as it is initialised in the method `bts()`, which is called before the `AlertDialog` is created, it will be `null`. Move its initialisation to after the `AlertDialog` creation.

Comment: I posted both Layout and LogCat.

Comment: And I also tried moving the bts(); to after the AlertDialog, and didn't work.

Comment: @VictorDomingosSantiago: just move the `txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);` line, not the whole `bts()` call, otherwise you'll get other problems! Looking at your LogCat, you might also need to initialise your dialog with `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());` rather than `Mec.this`...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Mec extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

  AlertDialog.Builder builder;
  LinearLayout lila;
  EditText et;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.loud);

      builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
      lila = new LinearLayout(this);
      et = new EditText(this);

      lila.addView(et);

      builder.setView(lila);
      builder.show();
  } 

}
```

That should give you a nice alert dialog with an EditText inside! :)
Now if you place builder.show() inside of an onClickListener of another button, the alert dialog will only show up when that button is clicked.  I hope that's what you're looking for.

EDIT: And to set the textviews, you would simply have to say something like textfield.setText(et.getText()); -- you might have to cast it as a String, but that's the basic idea...

Comment: I'm pretty new at this and I don't think I understood the code... I'm getting this error "Syntax error on token "Builder", VariableDeclarator expected after this token" on the "AlertDialog.Builder;" line.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a stupid mistake.. you of course need to set a variable name/identifier..  I edited the code.. should work.

Answer (score 0):

make your code like this

```
private void poptxt() {
AlertDialog InserirTXT = new AlertDialog.Builder(Mec.this).create();
LayoutInflater infle = getLayoutInflater();
View txtlayout = infle.inflate(R.layout.poptxt, null);
InserirTXT.setView(txtlayout);
tSup = (TextView) InserirTXT.findViewById(R.id.txtSuperior); //THE PROBLEM
txt = (EditText) InserirTXT.findViewById(R.id.et1);
InserirTXT.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String texto = (String) txt.getText().toString();
        tSup.setText(texto);
    }
});
InserirTXT.setCancelable(true);
InserirTXT.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
InserirTXT.show();
}
```

You are initializing the `tSup and txt` with the context of the `Activity` in which you set layout `loud` which does not have `R.id.txtSuperior and R.id.et1`. These two view are in your layout `poptxt`. Am I correct? And you are inflating `poptxt` in  `poptxt()`. So initialize them with the dialog View not with the `Activity's` View.